# Method to shuffle integers testing

Tags: java, collections, arraylist, shuffle

I have a method that is called `shuffle`, like the one I have shown below, that shuffles an ArrayList, of integers. I was wondering, do I have to test this method?

```
  public void shuffle(){
    Collections.shuffle(numbers);
  }
```

---

I am using this method to shuffle a deck of 52 cards, and in this case, it is kind of harder to see(by testing  if the cards are shuffled or not, because you might have two cards in a row with the same number or the same suit, which is still considered shuffled.

Comment: Try producing a Random seed..and apply to `Collections.shuffle` method...something like : `long seed = System.nanoTime();
Collections.shuffle(numbers, new Random(seed));`

Comment: In what context? If only you will ever use or edit this method, I would just test that Collections.shuffle(numbers) does what you expect. If others may edit this method in future, it *may* be worth writing a unit-test in case they decide to change your implementation, but do not understand/know the requirements. You could test edge cases like, what does shuffle do when given numbers containing duplicates, or what does shuffle do when given a collection which does not support the set operation.

Comment: @user1181847: typically default shuffling algorithms aren't strong enough to prevent attacks. Back in the days at least one online poker site had its shuffling algorithm figured out by pirates who then proceeded to beat other players.  Most online poker sites nowadays are using very advanced shuffling methods, some of them even going as far as using a physical device providing a "truly" random source. To prevent attacks you'd at least need a cryptographically secure pseudo-random number generator (CSPRNG). *Collections.shuffle()* ain't suitable if real money is involved (eg online poker sites)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There *is* still a point in testing trivial routines. You can test that

- it delegates to `Collections.shuffle` if that's a requirement of the routine
- it actually shuffles

which will let you know that the routine still upholds its contract should you desire to `refactor` later on.

Do you *need* to test it? No. Is it *pragmatic* to test? Perhaps not. But every bit of guarantee helps to verify the correctness of your program. Ultimately, it's for you to decide.

---

**EDIT**
It's good practice to design for testing. Essentially it's easier to test a routine which has no *side effects*, i.e.,

> a routine which acts on its inputs, calculates a value and returns the result.

Now since `Collections.shuffle` modifies an existing list a return value would seem ambiguous. Let's consider the second best option for testability

```
public void shuffle(List<?> l) {
    Collections.shuffle(l);
}
```

Whether such design is appropriate or not in *your* case I leave for you to judge. This was just a general fyi :)